# Can I write multiple elements with different classes with the same setatributte?

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
returnx.addEventListener('click', () => {

  newimage.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')
  maxbackground.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')
  returnx.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')
  creatortext.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')

})
```

and I would like something like this

```
returnx.addEventListener('click', () => {
  newimage,maxbackground,returnx,creatortext.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')
})
```

I can´t loop as long as they are completely different elements, and I wouldn't like to give it all the same class

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put together and use `forEach` loop, and add the `style` attribute.

```js
const names = [newimage, maxbackground, returnx, creatortext];

names.forEach( name => {
  name.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner, that could do the work for your specific need ?

```
[newimage, maxbackground, returnx, creatortex].forEach(x => x.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;') );
```

Here, I just put elements together in array so it's possible to loop.

*Edit : too slow to write answers...*